# Angular Material Tree - Checkbox changes are not reflected on ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview, angular-material-table

Checkbox changes are not reflected on ngmodel.

1. Changing the data doesnt update the template: (checkbox changes - see the example)
2. The only solution for moment to reload the datasource.data that will cause the tree to be collapsed all.
3. Im adding new data parent and nodes on every expand (thats my requirements)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-tree-example-8ss7qq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts&file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

[image]

Comment: which data are you trying to update, I can see that row.access value is updating

Comment: the chekboxes. Trying to check the parent wont change the child nodes.

Comment: @Mr.Stash yes. but the view is not updated. tried ngZone and changeRefDetection but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the following code and give it a try

1. I have replaced ngModel with the checked attribute.
2. After clicking checked reassigned the expanded state of all the items.
3. Modified the tempNodes storage logic.

```html
<mat-checkbox
  [checked]="row.Access"
  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
  (change)="onSelectionChanged($event, row, i, j)"
>
</mat-checkbox>
```

```
constructor() {
  this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[0]);

  this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach((node) =>
    this.tempNodes.push({
      ...node,
      expanded:
        this.treeControl.isExpanded(node) ||
        (node === this.treeControl.dataNodes[0] &&
          !this.treeControl.isExpanded(this.treeControl.dataNodes[0])),
    })
  );
}

logNode(clickedNode, index) {
  this.tempNodes = [];
  this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach((node) =>
    this.tempNodes.push({
      ...node,
      expanded:
        this.treeControl.isExpanded(node) ||
        (node === clickedNode && !this.treeControl.isExpanded(clickedNode)),
    })
  );

  ... // Add the rest of the method code here
}

onSelectionChanged(arg: MatCheckboxChange, obj: any, i, j) {
  if (this.treeControl.isExpanded(obj)) {
    let parentObj;

    this.dataSource.data.forEach(
      (data) => (parentObj = this.findParentObj(obj, data))
    );

    this.checkAllsubNodes(obj, arg, i, j);
    parentObj.Access = arg.checked;
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;
    this.setPreviousState();
  }
}

// Add the following methods

findParentObj(obj, data) {
  if (obj.CategoryID === data.CategoryID && obj.FolderName === data.FolderName) {
    return data;
  } else if (data.subFolder?.length) {
    let sourceData = null;
    data.subFolder.forEach((row) => {
      const temp = this.findParentObj(obj, row);
      if (temp) {
        sourceData = temp;
      }
    });
    return sourceData;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. With some modifications working cool. Will update the code.

Comment: Have updated the code .
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-tree-example-8ss7qq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts&file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html
 
There remain an issue. The elements of an expanded child are not affected by checkbox xhanges since the child is not detected as expanded. 

If i expand the Sub Empty and check/uncheck the Main Folder the childs will not be changed.

Comment: checkAllsubNodes(obj, arg, i, j) {
    console.log(this.treeControl.isExpanded(obj)); 

This will not detect expanded childs only when we click to them.

Comment: subFolder items are objects of the dataSource not the treeControl so !this.treeControl.isExpanded(obj) condition is always true for subFolder items, and it never gets to the third level

Comment: So there is no sense to check for the conditions checkAllsubNodes.

Comment: no, you need to compare the obj with treeControl.dataNodes find the matching node and then check if that node is expanded, or somehow add an expanded flag to the dataSource objects when they are expanded and directly check !obj.expanded

Comment: Yes. Good idea also with a variable. Just fixed by checking for  if (!obj.subFolder) instead of isExtended.  Thanks for all.